# Mupdf: how to reset the resolution of pdf view page PROPERLY when the CDialogEx(MFC) OnSize?

Tags: mupdf

my pdf file is rendering in a CDialogEx(it's MFC Class),and what i want is to reset the resolution when the Dialog resized.....

I find a solution via the [mupdf offical downloads site](http://mupdf.com/downloads/):first set the desired resolution with pdfapp_setresolution(...), then call pdfapp_reloadpage(...). This reaches my goal but not perfect, with this method the displaying dialog gets a conspicuous redrawing (first the background color, then recovered back normal)...

anybody have a better optimization? thanks

Comment: pdfapp_reloadpage() seems to only exist in the X11 port of mupdf, and if you're using MFC you are presumably not using X11. Please post the actual source code of your current implementation.

Comment: question have resolved by referencing the example code [source](https://mupdf.com/downloads/) (mupdf-1.11-source.tar.gz 2017-04-11 08:42 38M)(search API> void pdfapp_autozoom() in pdfapp.c source file)

Comment: (0) windows7 64bit (1) VS2015 Ent (3) MFC dev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st. resize the pdfapp_t object according to the view_window size via API pdfapp_onresize()

2nd. adjust the resolution of pdfapp_t object//#attentison# here the resolution needs some transformation on the basis of yr actual requirement, referencing the API pdfapp_autozoom() in pdfapp.c source file.

3rd. show page via pdfapp_showpage()

thats all :) maybe helpful to sb.

PS:lesson is that referencing the official document or example in details first :)